# Trouble with passing a Random object as an argument

Tags: java, syntax, parameters

I am having trouble passing a random object as an argument.

I made a new file to test it and I got the same errors. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Practice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random(1234);
    Spring (Random r);
  }

  void Spring (Random r) {
    r.nextInt(20);
  }
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
/tmp/Practice.java:5: error: ')' expected
    Spring (Random r);
                  ^
/tmp/Practice.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
    Spring (Random r);
                    ^
2 errors
```

Comment: This code is broken in several places. Have you tried reading your compiler errors?

Comment: You should be passing the arguments as `Spring (r);`

Comment: Also please use method name that starts with the lowercase (Uppercase are reserved for classes)

Comment: The only compile errors I'm getting are:                                                            practice.java:6: ')' expected
 Spring (Random r);
               ^
practice.java:6: illegal start of expression
 Spring (Random r);
                 ^

Comment: @Max Zoom thank you that worked... is that how I pass all arguments with just the value and not the type? I'll keep the methods lower-case. Thanks

Comment: @CodingWill yes, you just pass the variable if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues....

This is what you should be doing (see comments for explanation):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random(1234);
        //don't need Random here
        //also call static method
        Practice.Spring (r);
}
  //since you are calling a static method, you need to declare it static
  //also it's good practice to add the methods access modifier.
  private static void Spring (Random r) {
      r.nextInt(20);
}
```

Comment: Great. This is very helpful. Why would I want to make Spring private?

Comment: The way you had it before would have defaulted to `private`, this is just an explicit declaration. However, it's good practice to make everything private, unless there is a reason to make it public (like another class needing to access the method). In this case though, private would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To call Spring (...) you will first have to create an instance of your class. To achieve this you must call the constructor:

```
Practice myPractice = new Practice();
```

After this you can call your Spring method:

```
myPractice.Spring(r); //Random must be left out at this place - only when declaring the function interface
```